# How to add custom fields using umbraco cms?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog

Currently i'm working on project that's built into umbraco cms, now i want to add some functionality like add custom fields using umbraco so is there any way to add custom fields into project using umbraco ?

e.g. i have fields named "text,imageURL and name" now i want to save and (loop)fetch into particular div  tag in razor view.

i'd followed this link 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PtzyrEFG7I'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Data/Defining-content/

Content fields in Umbraco are called properties, and you define properties per document type - it's very easy to do via the backoffice as you'll see in the link.

The Youtube video you've found is for much more advanced scenarios than I think you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Custom field type: http://www.nibble.be/?p=89

For getting value by name

```
@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("text")
```

refer this razor ,good one:
https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet

Comment: hi thanks for your help i'd followed this link 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PtzyrEFG7I' is it proper way to do it ?